# how to find the area between $y=1$ and $\frac13(5-x)^{\frac 12}$

Tags: calculus, area, curves

I'm having trouble finding the area between these two curves shown in the first image. I have my attempt in the second.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The integral you're performing doesn't exist (at least in terms of real numbers). Notice that $\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{5-x}$ intersects the x-axis at $x=5$.

Comment: I think this one intersects at 5.5, sorry if the image is difficult to see. I evaluated 5 and I got 0.

Comment: To me, it looks like the curve meets the x-axis at $x=5$, and then carries on horizontally until $x=5.5$. This would suggest that you integrate \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{5-x} from $0$ to $5$, and subtract this from $11$. Then, add in the area of the two rectangles at the end of width $1/2$ and height $1$.

Comment: You were absolutely right. Thank you both so much!